# Supporting document as photos TLSContact: EEA Permit

Tags: immigration, eu-citizens, uk-visa, eu-spouses

I am applying for the EEA family permit, based on being a spouse of EEA National among the supporting documents is the Marriage certificate and printed photos during the stages of our relationship and wedding. The visa application center used in my Country is TLSContact and now they only scan supporting documents *(Supporting documents will be scanned whilst customers are at the visa application center, and then given straight back immediately.)*. As anyone used their service lately presenting printed photos as proof like am about to do? did they accept these pictures because I read they rejected photo albums from people and this caused their visa to be refused.

Comment: Were you married within the last two years?  Do you have any children with your wife?

Comment: No, Just got married 3 months ago